# How to use scrollTop in jquery when linking to a new page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code to smoothly scroll between links on a single page:

```
$(".navbar .nav a").bind('click',function(event){

    $("html, body").animate({
        scrollTop: $($(this).attr("href")).offset().top - (90) + "px"
    }, {
        duration: 1200,
        easing: "easeInOutExpo"
    });

    return false;
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

This works fine when the links are clicked on the same page. However, when they are linked to exernally:

- The offset doesn't apply; and
- The page doesn't scroll.

I would like to fix this by navigating to the new page, starting at the top and then scrolling down to the anchor. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Linking to an external page's internal link (assuming your own), your url should look something like page.html#target. On that external page, you can grab the target and scroll to it as you have now. Or you can set up the link differently so there is no default scroll to that ID. Parse the URl and grab target then scroll

Comment: also get rid of the preventDefault(), it is after the return false, which means it will never execute and since you are returning false, you don't need preventDefault